# GCP SLA for Persistent Disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been searching for the SLA for persistent disks but to no avail. The closest I can find is [compute engine's SLA](https://cloud.google.com/compute/sla). Can I safely assume this is also the SLA for persistent disks? Or GCP does not have SLA for persistent disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Persistent disks are high-performance block storage for virtual machine instances and are attached to the network interface. The SLA for persistent disks is embedded inside the official documentation of [Compute Engine Service Level Agreement (SLA)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/sla)

> "Downtime" means: For virtual machine instances: loss of external connectivity or persistent disk access for the Single Instance or, with respect to Instances in Multiple Zones, all applicable running instances.

Which means that if if your instances are not capable to access the persistent disk, it is then considered as a downtime and consequently the SLA applies.